# How to capture Floating point exception happening in the C++ code I am executing from Python using ctypes.CDLL

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a python program that interacts with some C++ code. I load the C++ functions from python using `ctypes.CDLL(path_to_compiled_c_code).function_name`. At some point the execution of my Python program stops with the message `Floating point exception (code dumped)`. I know this exception comes from the C++ but it doesn't say the line and diving into it is not an option. If I could capture that exception from my Python code that would be great but when this error happens the execution stops without any exception that I can capture, or at least I don't have any information regarding that in the stdout, just that single line.

How could I capture this from Python code?

Comment: How about dealing with the real problem (e.g. fixing the *C(++)* code, or passing the right data to it)? Since it's a co**r**e dump, you can't catch it. It's most likely a division by 0. Could we see some code (probably the *C* code compilation flags would also be useful)?  [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know that the most correct thing to to would be dealing with it but I said that diving into it is not an option for a reason and that is beyond this question. What do you mean by I can't catch since its a core dump? Isn't there any workaround I could take, maybe somehow handling the exit of the python execution in a specific way?

Comment: You could then use a debugging tool from *strace* family.